Proving that $(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x-1} \cdot (1+\frac{1}{x-c})^{x-c} \leq 1$
Assume $c \geq 1$. I want to show that the function
$$f(n) =  \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1} \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n-c}\right)^{n-c}$$
satisfies $f(n) \leq 1$ for all $n > c$.
My attempt: I think the fastest way to show this is by extending $f$ to $\mathbb R$ and show the result using derivatives. Notice that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = e^{-1} \cdot e =1$, so it suffices to show that $f(x)$ is increasing for $x > c$.
After computing the derivative, one notices that it suffices to show
$$\log\left( \frac{x-1}{x} \cdot \frac{x-c+1}{x-c} \right)  \geq \frac{c-1}{x(x-c+1)}.$$
I am stuck here.

$$
 \log f(x) = (x-1) \log \left( 1 - \frac 1x \right) +
 (x-c) \log \left( 1 + \frac {1}{x-c} \right)
$$
has the derivative
$$
 \log \left( 1 - \frac 1x \right) + \frac 1x 
+ \log\left( 1 + \frac {1}{x-c} \right) - \frac{1}{x-c+1} \\
= \log\left( \frac{x-1}{x} \cdot \frac{x-c+1}{x-c} \right) - \frac{c-1}{x(x-c+1)}.
$$
Using the estimate  $\log (u) \ge (u-1)/u$ (see for example here) this is
$$
 \ge \frac{c-1}{(x-1)(x-c+1)} - \frac{c-1}{x(x-c+1)} 
= \frac{c-1}{x(x-1)(x-c+1)} \ge 0
$$
for $x > c \ge 1$, so that $f$ is indeed increasing on $(c, \infty)$.

Alternative proof.
By Bernoulli inequality $(1 + u)^r \le 1 + ur$ for all $0 < r \le 1$ and $u \ge 0$, we have
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n-c}\right)^{\frac{n-c}{n-1}}
\le 1 + \frac{1}{n-c}\cdot \frac{n-c}{n-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{n-1}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1} \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n-c}\right)^{n-c}
\le \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1} \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1} = 1.$$

$\left(1+\frac{1}{n-c}\right)^{n-c} \le \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$ also follows from the (well-known) fact that $x \mapsto \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ is increasing in $x$.
